# how to track down the factory's property is getting updated from which other factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am novice to Angularjs, I am having lot of factories in my application, the scenario is lets assume like obj1 in factoryA. At some point of time when I console.log(obj1) , then it shows multiple properties inside it. It is getting  updated from other factories and controllers. Since it is big application I dont know the complete flow and it is very hard to find out. So, is there any way to track down history like from where and all the particular object in factory is invoked and updated ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the debugger keyword as breakpoints.

You shall be able to examine all values that are in the current scope.